# What time the line turn? Image processing

Tags: image-processing, geometry, processing

I'm using LeapMotion with Processing.
I want to draw a triangle with my hands , and make these line straight .
and my data is all 2D point(x,y) per frame

The triangle what I draw absolutly not straight.
So first I use "linear Regression" to draw a straight line.

and my question is

- What time the user turn when they draw a triangle?

(my opinion is to us "angle extremes" to detect what time its turn.)

- Is there some image processing technology to use?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the parametrized model of all 3 lines, what you need to do is find for each pair of lines the point that is the least distance from the two lines.

That is your corner.

For the lines, one linear regression would probably not do.  Perhaps do some ransac to find the lines and K-means to cluster the points to their lines.